# A conjecture I came up with while proving a number theory problem.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that $p_1, p_2...p_n$ are some distinct primes in increasing order(not necessarily exhaustive), defined if and only if $n \ge 2$. Prove that there exists a prime $q$ such that $q>p_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$ and $q<p_1  p_2  ...  p_n$.

Comment: Doesn't it simply follow from Bertrand's postulate? Take the largest $p_i$, so there is a prime number $p_i<q<2p_i$, and $2p_i$ is obviously not bigger than the product $p_1p_2...p_n$.

Comment: Just to clarify, since it is **not** given that $\{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n\}$ is an exhaustive list of all primes $\leq p_n$, you can **not** assume that $q = [-1] + [p_1 \times \cdots \times p_n]$, because $q$ might be divisible by some prime $\leq p_n$ that is not included in the list $\{p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_n\}.$  Have I interpreted the intent of the query correctly?

Comment: By taking $n=2$, $p_1 = 2$ and $p_2$ arbitrary, it’s fairly clear that Bertrand’s postulate is also implied by the statement.  So there is no hope for an argument more elementary than @Mark provides.  The claim is equivalent to Bertrand.